# OpenLayers3 - Add a source.vector from String, not url (for Layers)

Tags: openlayers, vector, kml

The current way to add layer from KML file is:

```
    var urlToKml = someUrl;
    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
               source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        url: urlToKml,
                        format: new ol.format.KML()
                    }),
                    visible: true
                });

   map.addLayer(vector);
```

I'd like to load my source from a string

(ie: where `urlToKml = "<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd'><Placemark><description>hrt</description><Style><IconStyle><Icon><href>data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==</href><gx:w>5</gx:w><gx:h>5</gx:h></Icon><hotSpot x='2.5' y='2.5' xunits='pixels' yunits='pixels'/></IconStyle></Style><Point><coordinates>2.335711304736855,49.10454920376088</coordinates></Point></Placemark></kml>";` )

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have your kml as string, there is no need to use `url` parameter

Check the following snip:

```
var kmlstring = "<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd'><Placemark><description>hrt</description><Style><IconStyle><Icon><href>data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==</href><gx:w>5</gx:w><gx:h>5</gx:h></Icon><hotSpot x='2.5' y='2.5' xunits='pixels' yunits='pixels'/></IconStyle></Style><Point><coordinates>2.335711304736855,49.10454920376088</coordinates></Point></Placemark></kml>";
//Your kml is projected in EPSG:4326
//and I assume your map is projected in 'EPSG:3857'
//Change them accordingly if different
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
var features = new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(kmlstring ,{
                       dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
                       featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'
                    });
vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
```

Comment: Just a small precision - I needed to add:
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({source: vectorSource}); map.addLayer(vector);
But thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help amigo!!!

Comment: Oh, and how did you know my KML projection is EPSG:4326?

Comment: I wasnt 100% sure but I just assumed from this `><Point><coordinates>2.335711304736855,49.10454920376088</coordinates>`